# Highcharts timeline chart with multiple axes

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I am trying to implement a `Highcharts` `timeline` chart with two `xAxis` - one of type `timeline` and another one of type `datetime` showing the same data. I managed to do this but I am having troubles with the position of the `dataLabels` on the `timeline xAxis`.

1. I don't want the labels to be alternating, so I have used `alternate: false`, but I want them to be displayed on the top of the `xAxis`, not underneath - which apparently is the default behavior with `alternate: false`.
2. I would like the two `xAxis` to be linked - when the user hovers over a point on one of the `xAxis` the point should be highlighted on both axes.
3. Would it be possible to enlarge the height of the boxes in the `timeline` axis and show the `dataLabels` inside the boxes?

Following you can see a screenshot of the current version and a `jsFiddle` live demo:

[image]

**Live demo:** - https://jsfiddle.net/wyek8t09/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set `distance` property to some negative value

---

```
series: [{
  dataLabels: {
    alternate: false,
    distance: -90
  },
  ...
}, ...]
```

2. Change the appearance in `state` properties. Use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events to connect points and `setState` method to change thier state.

---

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
    marker: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          fillColor: 'red'
        }
      }
    },
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          var secondSeriesI = this.series.index ? 0 : 1,
            secondSeries = this.series.chart.series[secondSeriesI];

          secondSeries.points[this.index].setState('hover');
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          var secondSeriesI = this.series.index ? 0 : 1,
            secondSeries = this.series.chart.series[secondSeriesI];

          secondSeries.points[this.index].setState('');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Increase value in `marker.height` property:

---

```
series: [{
  dataLabels: {
    alternate: false,
    distance: 0,
    marker: {
      height: 150
    }
  },
  ...
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g2zn1p63/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.marker

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.marker.states.hover

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.states.inactive

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.dataLabels.distance

Comment: Thanks for the well documented answer and the references! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: do you know how to get rid of the white space at the bottom of the second axis on this demo https://jsfiddle.net/4ws7c06g/23/ ? I want the two xAxis to be directly under each other and the whole chart height to be just enough to fit the content.

Comment: Hi @Stefan Stefanov, You can play with `chart.height` and `yAxis` position. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/53Lb9v6x/1/